# Validating AVRO schema on Confluent server

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

If we enable the property `confluent.value.schema.validation` on Confluent server, how is the actual validation performed? Does the broker deserialize the message and check its format? Or does it validate only that the message has the correct id of the schema?

Answer (score 0):

It would need to deserialize the data, even partially to actually get the ID, so yes, it does both.

Try testing by forging a Avro Kafka record with an existing ID but an invalid payload for the schema of that ID.

Comment: Schema id goes separately in the wire format. The question is if the broker deserializes and validates the actual message (value)

Comment: It is not "separate". ID is inserted between the magic byte and the record content (value and/or key). Look at [the demo](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html#demo-enabling-sv-on-a-topic-at-the-command-line) and you would see the record content does get validated, first because those records are not binary types that match the wire-format, but if they did, then the record content wouldn't adhere to the ID **within the record** (not separate)

Comment: Actually, I followed your advice and created the [demo](https://github.com/katyagorshkova/schema-validation-example). When I send the valid schema id but the random byte array as a content the message is sent successfully.